# How do I safely pass around an IO address that eventually gets passed into inline assembly?

Tags: assembly, gcc, avr

I have a short assembly snippet from an AVR project:

```
    uint8_t high = _BV(0);
    uint8_t low = ~high;
    uint8_t port_value = 0;
    asm volatile (
        "in %0, %1   \n\t"
        "or %0, %3   \n\t"
        "out %1, %0  \n\t"
        T1H_NOOP
        "and %0, %2   \n\t"
        "out %1, %0   \n\t"
        T1L_NOOP
    : "=r" (port_value)
    : "I" (_SFR_IO_ADDR(PORTB)), "r" (low), "r" (high));
```

The idea behind this block is to enable a particular pin (actual physical microprocessor pin) for a short amount of time (T1H_NOOP), then turn it off. The above code actually works flawlessly.

But, in the above code, the exact pin is hard-coded: PORTB, Pin 0 (`_BV(0)`). What I want is to be passing around an address such as this:

```
struct IO_ADDR {
    volatile uint8_t *port;
    uint8_t pin
}
```

So long as I remain in C code, that actually works.

```
    struct IO_ADDR addr = { .port = &PORTB, .bit = 0 };
    latch(&addr);

void latch(struct IO_ADDR *addr) {
    if (addr->bit >= 8) return;
    *(addr->port) &= ~(_BV(addr->bit));
    _delay_us(50);
}
```

And when I say that, I mean that I've run this through a simulator and seen the pins actuate as expected, plus I've paired this snippet with the assembly above and run it on the hardware. So, clearly, `*(addr->port) &= ...` is addressing the pin itself, and not pointer. Cool.

But when I do this, I get an assembly error:

```
        asm volatile (
            "in %0, %1   \n\t"
            "or %0, %3   \n\t"
            "out %1, %0  \n\t"
            T1H_NOOP
            "and %0, %2   \n\t"
            "out %1, %0   \n\t"
            T1L_NOOP
        : "=r" (port_value)
        : "I" (_SFR_IO_ADDR(*(addr->port))), "r" (low), "r" (high));
```

This error:

```
/nix/store/j31yaksw2dh82by2lgz1ysgh494cz6j2-src/neopixels.c: In function 'write_value':
/nix/store/j31yaksw2dh82by2lgz1ysgh494cz6j2-src/neopixels.c:29:9: warning: asm operand 1 probably doesn't match constraints
   29 |         asm volatile (
      |         ^~~
/nix/store/j31yaksw2dh82by2lgz1ysgh494cz6j2-src/neopixels.c:29:9: error: impossible constraint in 'asm'
```

This also occurs if I replace the addr->port parameter with `_SFR_IO_ADDR(addr->port)`.

`SFR_IO_ADDR(*(addr->port))` preprocesses to this:

```
        : "I" (
# 38 "src/neopixels.c" 3 4
              (((uint16_t) &(
# 38 "src/neopixels.c"
              *(addr->port)
# 38 "src/neopixels.c" 3 4
              )) - 0x20)
# 38 "src/neopixels.c"
              )
```

The final assembly should be this in the case of `PORTB`, address 0x24 on this particular piece of hardware (and ignoring the exact registers, which the compiler chose):

```
    in r18, 24   
    or r18, r21   
    out 24, r18
```

What do I need to do to pass that particular IO address to my assembly code?

Comment: Your basic problem is that you're using the IO address with an instruction that takes an immediate operand, so needs to be evaluated at compile time, but the address in general can only be determined at run time. You either need to make the IO address a constant that can always be evaluated at compile time, or use an instruction that takes a register or memory operand for the IO address. Note that the address space the IN and OUT instructions is different from what C pointers use. You need to subtract 0x20 to convert a memory address into an IO address.

Comment: Note there's really no need to use inline assembly here. GCC can generate IN and OUT instructions when the memory address used is a compile time constant and maps into a valid IO address after conversion.

Comment: Indeed the compiler can generate much better assembly code than you: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/rKshaM

Comment: I did start with C code. However, While the compiler can generate better assembly code, timing control on WS2812 chips is so tight that I cannot reliably generate timings in the 350 - 800ns range in C code on an 8Mhz processor.

Comment: If you need that precise of control of every instruction, beyond the example `t1h_noop` delay function I gave in the link above, then you should use regular assembly.

Comment: You can look at the assembly GCC generates for the C code snippet you showed that uses pointers.  Then you can just write the same type of thing in assembly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After another day of research, I found this answer:

```
        asm volatile (
            "ld %0, %1  \n\t"
            "or %0, %3  \n\t"
            "st %1, %0 \n\t"
            T1H_NOOP
            "and %0, %2 \n\t"
            "st %1, %0 \n\t"
            T1L_NOOP
        : "=r" (port_value)
        : "X" (*(addr->port)), "r" (low), "r" (high));
```

There were two key points involved. One of them is providing the `X` constraint instead of the `I` constraint, which actually means "the operand can be anything at all". This is sub-optimal, but the assembler did not accept some of the more obvious ones ("the operand is a non-relocatable memory address").

Additionally, I switched from the `in` and `out` assembler instructions, which as Ross Ridge points out in comments above, requires an immediate address that must be known at compile time, and to the `ld` and `st` instructions, which accept memory addresses.

As a last note, I had to change the number of NOP instructions in some of the T1H_NOOP, T1L_NOOP, T0H_NOOP, and T0L_NOOP macros in order to maintain the timing constraints that the [neopixel signalling protocol](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-neopixel-uberguide/advanced-coding#writing-your-own-library-2894697-13) requires.

All of this is painful enough that I did some reading about pulse width modulation and timer/clock circuits with interrupts, as that feels like it would generate more reliable timings than my active busy loops. However, the addition of interrupt handlers would increase my code complexity in ways that I'm not prepared to handle right now.

Comment: If the address *can* be a constant, you might wrap this code in `if __builtin_constant_p`.  Then have two variations, one with `I` and one with `X`.  Since this condition is resolved at compile time, it should give you the best of both worlds.  NB check out the [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#index-_005f_005fbuiltin_005fconstant_005fp), which points out things like how inlined functions won't properly detect constants unless you enable optimizations (which makes sense).

Comment: I believe there are definitely some instances in which this can be a compile-time constant. I happen to have a case in which it does not. Do you think that this option would save any program space?

Comment: It's hard to speak in absolutes about what optimizers might do.  But I would expect that a construct like `if __builtin_constant_p do I else do X` would optimize the way you'd expect.  There'd be no reason (in optimized builds) for both cases to ever be included.  Is using "I" "smaller" than using "X"?  Couldn't say, I don't know AVR that well.

Answer (score 0):

The `"I"` assembly constraint [requires it's operand to be a constant](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html#Machine-Constraints) (or, with -O1/-O2, a constant expression) so unfortunately you won't be able to pass it as a parameter.